# Use template in CSS

Tags: css, templates

I want to know if it's possible to use "template-like" in css like this :

HTML :

```
<p padding-5>Padding 5</p>
<p padding-10>Padding 10</p>
```

CSS :

```
padding-x {
    padding: x px;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Check out LESS or SASS or SCSS, its not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: In sass (or less) how can i get a value from html ?

Comment: You do not, you specify it prior to compile time or use JavaScript. But honestly, where is the difference between `class="padding-5"` and `style="padding: 5px;"` ? there is none. Its a code smell if you are trying to do it.

Comment: i think  i don't understand what you suggere. 
i don't care how to code it. But i just want to have something who add padding with value in my html code without have X class in my css file

Comment: You are having an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I perfectly understand what you want.  Imagine that it *were* possible. Then you would write `class="padding-15"` to get your 15 pixels of padding. That is *exactly* the same thing as writing `style= padding: 15px"` *which already works*. Inline-styles however *are a code smell*. If you want to do that, you are building your HTML/CSS wrong. What you want is a tight coupling between HTMl and CSS. Well, the goal is the *decouple* it.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple: No, (in vanilla CSS) it's not possible. 
And actually i don't see a use-case for this since you can simply use the style itself then applying a class with only one attribute. You can use variables (e.g. for predefined colors) in [less](http://lesscss.org/) or in [sass](https://sass-lang.com/) tho.

Comment: For example with bootstrap they are 12 lines for each columns (col-1 -> 12) i just want to have 1 line and set the value i want.

Comment: Yes, this is possible (at least kind of). But the number for example "col-md-8" has a width of "66.666667%"  which has no direct relation to the number in the class. FYI Bootstrap also uses SASS => http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/

Comment: I think you should have a look at the grid CSS file of bootstrap. This should be what you are looking for: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_grid-framework.scss